# vimrc to be cross-platform and synced with Dropbox.

Tags: windows, linux, vim, dropbox

I'v been using vim/gVim so far in my Linux Machine, and I have a Windows machine as well. In this windows machine I'm mainly notepad++.

I would like to store all my `.vimrc` settings and `.vim` folder in Dropbox, and create symbolic links in Linux pointing to them, and them do the same in my Windows machine.

I have plenty of "home shortcut notation" (don't if this is the correct name) `~` in my configuration, and would like to know if writing down for example $HOME instead of ~ it's going to work: this way, I can create some symbolic links in Windows as well that points to these files (I'm using Windows 7, so my home is c:\Users\username).

Any other pitfalls or recommendations when creating vimrc cross-plataform with Dropbox?

Comment: I think, this question should better be asked over at superuser.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly what I do, and it works like a charm for me. The only place I use `$HOME` instead of `~` is for the backup directories, but that works fine. The main problem I run into is that editing the `.vimrc` file on Windows never works quite right, so I just edit it on OS X instead.

Comment: Not exactly like a charm since I needed to create a lot of symlinks, but in the end it worked well. Not flawlessly because of the .vimrc problem (I can't edit from windows because it keeps me saying my file c:\users\user/.vimrc doesn't exist), but I can live with it. :) This is a minor problem when I thought about creating different vim configuration files each time I want to use them cross-plataform...

Answer (score 7):

I do a bunch of customization of my .vimrc, but it's all based on capabilities, rather than platform.

I check for the different `has("gui_*")` flags, and also check `has("unix")`. This way I avoid dealing with messy platform dependent path issues.

Comment: This is already being done, thanks for the suggestion anyway. What I would like is to edit a config here at work and be available at home.

Answer (score 3):

If you use vim from within Cygwin, you can easily distinguish the platform inside the .vimrc file like this:

```
let s:sys=system('uname -s | perl -pe "chomp"')
if s:sys == "Linux"
  " do Linux stuff here
endif
```

and similar for `s:sys == "Cygwin_NT"`. If you're using a natively compiled vim under Win, e.g., Gvim, you'll have to find another system call, that is understood by both your Linux shell and the Win cmd.

Comment: I dont have too much specific plataform customizations in my vim/gVim, I was more interested in keeping them in sync, so if I change something at work it would be available at home.